# running grunt with jenkins user

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins

I have a script running on jenkins that does some stuff. The problem is the last part, changing directory and running `grunt` as the jenkins user.

I get the following output :
`[4mRunning "env:dev" (env) task[24m`

`[4mRunning "sass:dist" (sass) task[24m`

`[4mRunning "less:dist" (less) task[24m`
`[32m>> [39m1 stylesheet created.`

`[4mRunning "jshint:all" (jshint) task[24m`

`✔ No problems`

`[4mRunning "eslint:target" (eslint) task[24m`

`[4mRunning "csslint:all" (csslint) task[24m`
`[32m>> [39m4 files lint free.`

`[4mRunning "mkdir:upload" task[24m`

`[4mRunning "copy:localConfig" (copy) task[24m`

`[4mRunning "concurrent:default" (concurrent) task[24m`
`[4mRunning "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task[24m`
`[33m[nodemon] 1.11.0[39m`
 `[33m[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs[39m`
  `[33m[nodemon] watching: gruntfile.js modules/*/server/views/*.html`
`server.js config/**/*.js
 modules/*/server/**/*.js` 
`modules/*/server/config/*.js[39m`
`[32m[nodemon] starting`
 ``` node --debug server.js``[39m`` ```
    `[4mRunning "watch" task[24m`
 `Waiting...`
`Debugger listening on [::]:5858`

`[31m[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...[39m`
`Build was aborted`

Does anyone know how to bypass this error? Thank you !

[EDIT]
Sorry, forgot to add more details. Apparently the `grunt` command only works if you execute it as the `root` user. When executing it with any other user, even if it has root privileges, it gives the output i wrote ^. I need it to work from the script i made on the `jenkins server`, for the `jenkins node slave`. Any tips or ideas?